# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.Referenceable

Tags: osgi, activemq-classic

I have been trying to use activeMQ from an OSGi bundle and I have been running into some issues. I have been getting the one above now and I'm not sure what I need to do. Normally when I get this error it just means that you didn't import the package that you needed, but I have already added the javax.naming package in my manifest file.

This is what my manifest file looks like.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.activemq.test
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.activemq.test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-Activator: com.activemq.test.App
Import-Package: javax.jms,
 javax.naming,
 org.osgi.framework
Require-Bundle: ActiveMQExportTest;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

I am running the activeMQ helloworld application that they provide on their website. It works great when I run it normally, but if you wrap it into an osgi bundle it starts to fail.

Edit: I don't know if it's relevant, but the Required-Bundle is the activeMQ-all jar wrapped in a plugin to expose the packages that I need.

Stack Trace. If you need something else, let me know.

```
[7/30/13 9:14:17:782 CDT] 00000018 LogService-64-com.ibm.ws.org.apache.aries.proxy.1.0.2        E CWWKE0701E: FrameworkEvent ERROR Bundle:com.ibm.ws.org.apache.aries.proxy.1.0.2(id=64) java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unexpected error from weaving hook.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WeavingHookConfigurator.processClass(WeavingHookConfigurator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.common.AbstractWovenProxyAdapter.visit(AbstractWovenProxyAdapter.java:228)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.SerialVersionUIDAdder.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.weaving.SyntheticSerialVerUIDAdder.visit(SyntheticSerialVerUIDAdder.java:60)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.weaving.WovenProxyGenerator.getWovenProxy(WovenProxyGenerator.java:54)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.weaving.ProxyWeavingHook.weave(ProxyWeavingHook.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WovenClassImpl.call(WovenClassImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHookPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHooksPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WovenClassImpl.callHooks(WovenClassImpl.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WeavingHookConfigurator.processClass(WeavingHookConfigurator.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at com.ibm.activemq.test.App$HelloWorldProducer.run(App.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.Referenceable
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.common.AbstractWovenProxyAdapter.checkInterfacesForSerializability(AbstractWovenProxyAdapter.java:308)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.common.AbstractWovenProxyAdapter.visit(AbstractWovenProxyAdapter.java:231)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.SerialVersionUIDAdder.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.weaving.SyntheticSerialVerUIDAdder.visit(SyntheticSerialVerUIDAdder.java:60)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.weaving.WovenProxyGenerator.getWovenProxy(WovenProxyGenerator.java:54)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.weaving.ProxyWeavingHook.weave(ProxyWeavingHook.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WovenClassImpl.call(WovenClassImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHookPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHooksPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WovenClassImpl.callHooks(WovenClassImpl.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.weaving.WeavingHookConfigurator.processClass(WeavingHookConfigurator.java:68)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.Referenceable
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    ... 68 more
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would gladly take them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you have a static reference to a class/interface that is missing you get `NoClassDefFoundError`, wheras the checked exception `ClassNotFoundException` usually happens when somebody calls `Class.forName` or one of its variants.

My suspicion is that the exception doesn't even come from the bundle whose manifest you have shown above. I.e. one of your dependencies may use reflection to load a class that depends on `javax.naming.Reference` but that bundle does not import the package.

Perhaps if you post a full stack trace it might shed some light on the problem. Please update your question with this information, and I will update this answer if I see anything.

Comment: I posted the stack trace. I only have two bundles in this project, one of which is the ActiveMQ jar bundled up to export some of its packages and the helloworld bundle. At the moment I have the helloworld bundle importing javax.naming. If I try to have the ActiveMQ one import javax.naming eclipse won't even publish. I just get a message saying --> ActiveMQExportTest_1.0.0 failed to resolve.: Unsatisfied import package javax.naming_0.0.0.

Comment: "Eclipse won't even publish"... what does that mean?? Is this an error from the runtime, or is it a tooling issue? `javax.naming` is from the JRE, so published by the system bundle, I don't see how it would be unresolved, unless you completely overrode the framework exports.

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear, when you right click on server in eclipse and select publish so that the newest code is deployed. When I do this it gives me the error above. And I'm with you, I don't know how it doesn't know what it is.

Comment: Okay so you need to look at the import in your bundle, and work out which bundle's export it is wired to.